# jQuery centre content in full screen slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, center, supersized

I'm using *Supersized* full-screen jQuery slider plugin. I'm trying to centre content on each slide and have it stay there upon window resize. The issue is it keeps loading offset and then when I resize the window slightly it jumps to the correct position. I've tried lots of different code but can't seem to get anything to work correctly for each slide.

**Some example images:**

First slide loads correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1kVU.jpg

Second slide offset (until window resize): https://i.stack.imgur.com/a88Yf.jpg

**JavaScript Centring Code:**

```
jQuery.fn.centerslide = function () {
this.css("position","absolute");
this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
return this;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.container').centerslide();
$(window).resize(function(){$('.container').centerslide()});
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
  <div id="slides">
<ul class="slides-container">
    <li id="slide1">    
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
            <p>Praesent quis elementum mi. Nam vel mattis ligula. Donec vehicula tristique diam et laoreet. Phasellus ornare, lorem quis fringilla mollis, velit eros accumsan dolor, sit amet pellentesque sem lorem sed sapien.</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="slide2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
            <p>Praesent quis elementum mi. Nam vel mattis ligula. Donec vehicula tristique diam et laoreet. Phasellus ornare, lorem quis fringilla mollis, velit eros accumsan dolor, sit amet pellentesque sem lorem sed sapien.Praesent quis elementum mi. Nam vel mattis ligula. Donec vehicula tristique diam et laoreet. Phasellus ornare, lorem quis fringilla mollis, velit eros accumsan dolor, sit amet pellentesque sem lorem sed sapien.Praesent quis elementum mi. Nam vel mattis ligula. Donec vehicula tristique diam et laoreet. Phasellus ornare, lorem quis fringilla mollis, velit eros accumsan dolor, sit amet pellentesque sem lorem sed sapien.</p>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>

<nav class="slides-navigation">
  <a href="#" class="next"></a>
  <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
</nav>
```

Hope I've provided enough info. Any help is most appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I have developped a small function to center div :

```
function center_div(mon_div)
{
    $('#' + mon_div).css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $('#' + mon_div).outerWidth()) / 2) +  $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#' + mon_div).css('left', Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $('#' + mon_div).outerWidth()) / 2) +  $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
    });
}
```